# :app:jillDebugPackagedLibraries FAILED

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 and can build fine with the standard toolchain, however when enabling jack:

```
jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
```

I get:

```
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:jillDebugPackagedLibraries'.
    > com.android.jill.JillException

    * Try:
    Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.typeToUntypedDesc(MethodBodyWriter.java:2971)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.getUnnamedLocalId(MethodBodyWriter.java:2923)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.getLocalVariable(MethodBodyWriter.java:2909)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.writeLocalAccess(MethodBodyWriter.java:2479)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.writeInsn(MethodBodyWriter.java:1048)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.writeBody(MethodBodyWriter.java:567)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.writeJavaMethodBody(MethodBodyWriter.java:464)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.writeMethodBody(MethodBodyWriter.java:404)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.writeMethod(MethodBodyWriter.java:332)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.MethodBodyWriter.write(MethodBodyWriter.java:259)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.ClassNodeWriter.writeMethods(ClassNodeWriter.java:305)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.ClassNodeWriter.writeClass(ClassNodeWriter.java:106)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.ClassNodeWriter.write(ClassNodeWriter.java:69)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.JavaTransformer.transform(JavaTransformer.java:291)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.JavaTransformer.transformToZip(JavaTransformer.java:250)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.JavaTransformer.transformJavaFiles(JavaTransformer.java:232)
    at com.android.jill.frontend.java.JavaTransformer.transform(JavaTransformer.java:161)
    ... 7 more
```

Has anyone else seen this, and if so how was this resolved?